# flutter photo view plugin after upgrade get this error

Tags: flutter, dart

**The named parameter 'loadFailedChild' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'loadFailedChild'.",**

```
 Widget renderPhotoView(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: SizeFit.screenWidth,
  height: SizeFit.screenHeight,
  color: Colors.black,
  child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
    builder: (ctx, index) {
      return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
        imageProvider: NetworkImage(widget.images[index]),
        initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1,
      );
    },
    loadingBuilder: (ctx, event) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: event == null ? 0 : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / event.expectedTotalBytes,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    onPageChanged: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
        _title = '${index + 1}/${images.length}';
      });
    },
    scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    pageController: _pageController,
    itemCount: widget.images.length,
    loadFailedChild: Image.asset(TKImages.image_path + 'find_none_image.png'),
    backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
    gaplessPlayback: false,
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

According to `photo_view` plugin [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/changelog), the `loadFailedChild` parameter is removed from version 0.11.0
you should use `errorBuilder` instead

Comment: try errorBuilder already also same issue
 "message": "The named parameter 'errorBuilder' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'errorBuilder'.",

Comment: unfortunately `PhotoViewGallery` doesn't have errorBuilder. you can copy the photo_view_gallery.dart code to your project and add errorBuilder your self and pass it to `PhotoView` for now.

Comment: where to copy the photo_view_gallery.dart
so that mean i need to add new file with photo_view_gallery.dart
and on inside create errorBuilder ?

Comment: @xiaohao yes. for example in widgets folder of your project.
but the better solution is to fork the package code in github, add the feature, and create a pull request. but for now, you can just copy the code of package into your project and add errorBuilder locally